# Statistics on correlations in fMRI data

Tags: time-series, correlation, pearson-r, z-score

I have rodent fMRI time-series data for a number of brain regions, and I need to assess the significance of the similarity between the signals from different brain regions *before* and *after* a manipulation. I've looked through various papers, but I'm new to statistics and confused by the variety (and lack of clarity) in the academic papers on this topic. The data have been pre-processed (by standard MRI methods in a program called afni) and I have already regressed out motion artifacts. I'm working in Matlab.

I know I can look at the correlation (via Pearson's r) between each set of regions, and then convert those values to z-scores using Fisher's z-transform. I believe I can then subtract the z-scores before and after the manipulation and calculate the confidence interval.

However, this is where I get lost. The subtracted z-scores are quite small (~ 0- 0.1), and the confidence interval is something like +/- 0.02. This may not be particularly surprising, since this is resting-state fMRI data and effects do tend to be small. I'm not sure. But I don't know how to go from these values to a statement about significance (i.e. which regions are significantly correlated).

Is my basic approach correct? If not, how should I be thinking about this problem? Any suggestions or links to resources would be much appreciated!